# "Parameter 'dateRange' is required", when 'dateRange' is provided, what format should it be?

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get some data from the following API `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics`.

Here is the code I'm using to do it

```
def get_ad_analytics_v2(token: str) -> str:
    url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
        'pivot': 'ACCOUNT',
        'dateRange': json.dumps({
            'start': {
                'month': 5,
                'year': 2019,
                'day': 28
                },
            'end': {
                'month': 5,
                'year': 2022,
                'day': 28
                }
            }),
        'timeGranularity': 'DAILY'
        }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    print(response)
    return response
```

And I get a response:
{'message': "Parameter 'dateRange' is required", 'status': 400}

What should be the format of dateRange?

I tried different formats:

```
'dateRange': '{start = 1546300800000, end = 1609459200000}',

'dateRange': '(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2022))',

'dateRange': '(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2022))',
```

I am trying to get a non error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
so I was finally able to go further. The working code is:

```
def get_ad_analytics_v2(token: str) -> str:
    url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2'
    headers = { 'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    params = {
        'q': 'analytics',
        'dateRange.start.day': '1',
        'dateRange.start.month': '1',
        'dateRange.start.year': '2022',
        'pivot': 'COMPANY',
        'timeGranularity': 'DAILY'
        }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    return response
```

The working format for dateRange is:

```
        'dateRange.start.day': '1',
        'dateRange.start.month': '1',
        'dateRange.start.year': '2022',
```

Now the api is returning the error:
"{'serviceErrorCode': 3, 'message': 'Missing facet', 'status': 400}"
But this is connected with adding some more parameters which, by the way, are not so easy to understand from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=curl#metrics-available-1)

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not the format which is incorrect. You are trying to include the `'dateRange'` parameter as a header, but the LinkedIn API documentation specifies that the `'dateRange'` parameter should be included as a query string parameter in the URL.

To include the `'dateRange'` parameter in the query string of the URL, you can use the `params` parameter of the `requests.get()` function.

Second, you should leave out the `json.dumps()` call. The following code shouldn't lead to an error:

```
import requests

def get_ad_analytics_v2(token: str) -> str:
    url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics'
    params = {
        'q': 'analytics',
        'dateRange.start.day': '1',
        'dateRange.start.month': '1',
        'dateRange.start.year': '2022',
        'timeGranularity': 'DAILY',
        'pivot': 'COMPANY'
        }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
        }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    print(response)
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, after changes I still get an error which I uploaded in the updated question

Comment: @Jan you are on the right track, here's the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http#sample-request) the documentation gives on using this API endpoint. Do note even `pivot` is a query parameter.

Comment: Hmm, you don't seem to have looked at the example carefully, the example shows you exactly how to specify the `dateRange` parameter. Oh, I guess I linked another example, look at this one instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http#sample-request

Comment: Jan, Abdul Aziz Barkat, your right, but I am following the LI documentations, and as you can see in my edited question, the format of 'dateRange' in Python is still wrong, while in Postman it seems to be ok, and as far as I can see, they are the same ?